# Tables Next to Paragraph Tags not displaying on different lines as expected

Tags: html, internet-explorer, html-table, internet-explorer-9, paragraph

The following displays with each paragraph tag and the table on their own lines in IE9 exactly as I would want.

In IE9 Compatibility Mode, the last two `<P>` tags run up against the table as if the tale is floating.

Why?  And how do I make it stop?

**Edit**

Just to add to this, IE 9 Compatibility mode = "IE 9 Compatibility Mode, IE 7 Standards".
It displays just fine in IE 8 Standards.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN\"     \"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd\">
<HTML>
<BODY>
<DIV >
<P>a</P>  
<P>b</P>  
<TABLE style="WIDTH: 500px; float : none;" border="1" cellSpacing="1" cellPadding="1"     align="left">  
<TBODY>  
<TR>  <TD>1</TD>  <TD>2</TD>  <TD>3</TD>  <TD>4</TD></TR>  
<TR>  <TD>5</TD>  <TD>6</TD>  <TD>7</TD>  <TD>8</TD></TR>
</TBODY>
</TABLE>  
<P >c</P>  
<P >d</P>
</DIV>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've viewed the code in IE7 - IE9 as well as other browsers and it is rendering
properly in all of them.

I was able to duplicate your problem if I removed `float:none` from the table styling.

Once I had the problem duplicated, removing `align=left` from your TABLE tag fixed it.

Best,

Cynthia

Comment: You got it.  Removing the align=left fixes it.  I would have never guessed to do that. Thanks!

Comment: Not a problem - happy to help!